# Android - how to: load google/facebook user profile in 1 activity and set the listener result to any active/current activity

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, google-signin

I have:

```
+----------+
|user class|
+-----+----+
      |
+-----+-----+
|App Class  |
+-----------+
|User object|
|GoogleAPI  |
|FB API     |
+-----+-----+
      |
      +----not------+------a------+--sequential-+--activity---+
      |             |             |             |             |
+-----+-----+ +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+
|Activity 1 | |Activity 2 | |Activity 3 | |Activity 4 | |Activity 5 |
+-----------+ +-----------+ +-----------+ +-----+-----+ +-----+-----+
```

in the activity 1, i may trigger both google API and FB API to get user basic profile: FName, LName, Email, Profile Pict (asynchronously), then from there my app will 'not care' / wait until i have the result from Google and FB, user may go to any other activity (activity 2 or Activity 3 or any other other) - once Google or FB send the result, i would like to store the data in my user class (object in my app class)

if i go to activity 2 (for example) and the user profile result has been returned before i go to activity 2, then it's easy, i just call user object to present the data in activity 2 - because the data is there already.

**the question is**: if i go to any other activity but the result is not back yet, how to setup a listener, to load the result to the active activity?
e.g. i'm in activity 3, the profile result is not ready, then i may just show loading text (for example) but then when the result come from google/FB, i need to load the result to the current activity respectively.

is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you try to do it using a Broadcast Receiver or using service?

Comment: Thats one of my point which one is the right one to achieve this, broadcast receiver or service?

Comment: You can user a service to register listeners from every activity. You can notify all the listeners once you get the user details from FB and Google.
Since every activity has a listener registered, the listener on the current activity that you are in will trigger.